# cells.text returns value in 1 instance and nothing in second instance

Tags: string, vba, function, range, runtime-error

I've got the following question:

This line `wsMotiv.Range("motiv_naam") = Cells(iRijnummer, iKolomnrNaam).Text` gives a name (string) value. Why doesn't the line `s = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(iRijnummer, iKolomnrNaam).Text` do the same? It passes `" "`.

```
    Sub (whatev)
       AantalZichtbareRows
            Dim rng As Range
            Dim row As Range
            Dim StrFileName As String
            'If Aantalregels > 1 Then
             Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
             For Each row In rng.Rows
               iRijnummer = row.row
               If iRijnummer > 1 Then
                  Windows(c_SourceDump).Activate
                  wsMotiv.Range("motiv_cid") = Cells(iRijnummer, iKolomnrCorpID).Text
                  wsMotiv.Range("motiv_naam") = Cells(iRijnummer, iKolomnrNaam).Text
                  wsMotiv.Range("motiv_ldg") = Cells(iRijnummer, iKolomnrHuidigeLeidingGevende).Text
                  Worksheets("stambestand").Activate
                  'naamOpmaken

                  Dim s As String: s = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(iRijnummer, iKolomnrNaam).Text
                  Dim Position As Long, Length As Long
                  Dim n As String

                  Position = InStrRev(s, " ")
                  Length = Len(s)
                  n = Right(s, Length - Position)
               End If
             Next row
        End Sub
```

Comment: If you have 2 questions, it is a good idea to ask them separately.

Comment: I've thought about that. Decided against it because it's likely to be the same issue in two occurrences. If it proves not to be the case I'll split them up.

Comment: @Vityata :Changed it to 1 question, you helped me fix the 2nd issue (provided different viewpoint).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to the `ActiveSheet` in `Cells(iRijnummer, iKolomnrNaam).Text` and to the first worksheet in `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(iRijnummer, iKolomnrNaam).Text`. Probably they are different. Try this to see:

```
Sub TestMe
   Debug.Print wsMotiv.Name
   Debug.Print Worksheets(1).Name
   Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Name
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me solve the second issue. I did use the right workbook/sheet at the right time, however, I didn't pass a row value. So the 'Cells' code didn't have all the parameters filled.

Comment: @MyName - so this does not fix the first problem? Do you get the same result for all three?

Comment: Again, thanks. I fixed the first issue and then it still didn't work. Thought  it had to be a different problem (but it wasn't). So it's solved. Thanks a lot.
I removed the workbooks references so it only shows the line beginning with cells().text. that did the trick